# The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, asp.net-core

I am trying to save changes to my DB on a filter that I created that inherits the `ActionFilterAttribute`. Basically the filter is a basic API log that logs all the requests made to my API. It is written in .NET Core 2.2.

The error I am getting is follows:

> SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The stream ended unexpectedly.

This **only** occurs on this filter and not on any of my controllers that are using the DB context.

I am registering the filter in my `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AthenaContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:AthenaDB"]));
    services.AddScoped<LogFilter>();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {Title = "Athena API", Version = "v1"}); });
}
```

And then decorating the API class with: `[ServiceFilter(typeof(LogFilter))]`

The actual filter (for brevity I removed some of the unnecessary code):

```
public class LogFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public readonly AthenaContext _db;

    public LogFilter(AthenaContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    ........
        //Log the request
        _db.ApiLogs.Add(new ApiLog
        {
            EndPoint = $"{controllerName}/{actionName}",
            RequestHeader = requestHeader,
            RequestBody = requestBody,
            IpAddress = ipAddress
        });

        //Save the DB changes
        _db.SaveChanges();

        //Execute the base request
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
```

Comment: Suggest you post a minimal repro instead of all these distractions.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to debug issue.  Check the response status which should be 200 Done.  The error indicates you are getting some besides 200 Done.  Http uses TCP as the transport layer so every http messages consists of one or more TCP messages.  A TCP maximum size is ~1500 bytes.  The error could also mean your TCP is closing which will show up in the sniffer as [FIN] (finish).

Comment: Do you have any related error messages in the SQL Server error log?